# Sending Emails from a WPF Application

Tags: wpf, email, system.net.mail

I am building a WPF application, and 1 of the requirements is for the user to send me feedback through an email.

Now I have developed a method found on the Microsoft Site :-

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310263

which worked.  However I have some reservations about it since what if the user does not have Outlook installed?  And also I do not like the popup command where it asks you if its ok to use Outlook to send the mail.

Is there any other solution?  I do not wish to ask the user for his SMTP Host since most of my users won't know how to get that.

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this problem and decided to bypass it by sending e-mail from my server.

The problem is that to send e-mail you need the user's server info (SMTP host, username, password, e-mail address) or, to use software already on the system that knows this info already (outlook) - and that assumes the user can send SMTP mail at all (some webmail services don't have an SMTP option).

So what I've done is to post the content from my app to a simple ASP.net application on my web site and send the mail from there - that way I don't need to worry about SMTP and it also works great with my spam filtering (the app only sends e-mail to me so it can't be used by spammers and it bypasses my own spam filtering so I don't have to worry about losing feedback messages).

Update - here is the example you requested:

Here is my helper method for doing simple HTTP POST:

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    os.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null) return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

and the usage is:

```
            HttpPost("http://example.com/Default.aspx",
                "&email=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(form.EMail) +
                "&data=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(errorText));
```

In this example errorText is the multi-line return value from Exception.ToString()

On the server side there's a simple IHttpHandler (but it can be any server side app, originally it was a WebForms page) that reads the data from HttpContext.Request.Params, formats it as an e-mail and sends it to me using my own mail server - but you can just put it in a database if you want to bypass the whole e-mail thing (I wrote it using e-mail because it saved me writing the backend admin and let me reuse my contact form app)

Comment: Hi Nir, do you have any example on how to do that?  I basically am putting all the data in an XML file and attaching that file.  I was thinking of using a simple FTP connection to my server an put the files there, and then build a small Admin application to download and process these files.

Comment: @Johann - I've added example for uploading the data using HTTP POST

Comment: THanks for the example NIR.  I have decided to go with the WCF Rest and Stream example, and I am almost there, just some tweaking needed to allow for large file streaming.  You can see my thread here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779394/uploading-large-xml-to-wcf-rest-service-400-bad-request

Comment: @Johann - This is old code, I would've probably done something else if I wrote that today, but I don't know if I would use the heavyweight WCF for such a simple job where WebClient.UploadString would do (unless you get really long feedback)

Comment: @Nir, actually I "could" get long feedback, since the user has the ability to attach screenshots, which I turn into streams for transformation into XML.  I would say I am quite happy with the solution now, but as I said am a newbie to these things, so I have to investigate and discover more

Comment: @Johann - well, if you can attach screenshots (or other large files) that changes everything